# ArcGIS Time Slider that controls two maps/dataframes

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, timeslider

I have two maps/dataframes on the same webmap with various data throughout the USA. Both maps use a geocoder to be able to zoom to your area of interest in the USA and compare one place with another. I am using the same arcgis server layer for both maps/dataframes, but I can't figure out how to get the timeslider to control both maps/dataframes...any clues or examples out there?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/how-to-apply-arcgis-time-slider-on-multiple-data-frames-at-once?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. I actually saw this one, but there were no answers so I thought I would try to rephrase. If I get no responses then I'll go ahead and delete my question to avoid redundancy!

Comment: I think you can leave this one; you specifically mention web mapping and Server while the other one doesn't. They may have different answers.